Spring Cloud Function Gson library error when running locally
I am developing a sample Spring Cloud function using below configuration. When I run the function locally and try to access the URL locally getting  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Strictness error.
To mitigate this error I need to exclude the GsonAutoconfiguration class. Is this expected?
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.azlearning</groupId>
    <artifactId>az-email-sender-function</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>az-email-sender-function</name>
    <description>Azure Email Sender function</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot-thin-layout.version>1.0.31.RELEASE</spring-boot-thin-layout.version>

        <!-- Spring Boot start class! WARING: correct class must be set! -->
        <start-class>com.azlearning.functionapp.AzEmailSenderFunctionApplication</start-class>

        <!-- AZURE FUNCTION CONFIG -->
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.36.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <functionAppName>email-sender-funapp</functionAppName>
        <functionAppRegion>Region</functionAppRegion>
        <functionResourceGroup>az-cert-resource-group</functionResourceGroup>
        <functionAppServicePlanName>PlanName</functionAppServicePlanName>
        <functionPricingTier>PricingTier</functionPricingTier>
        <spring-cloud.version>2024.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <resourceGroup>${functionResourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
                    <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
                    <appServicePlanName>${functionAppServicePlanName}</appServicePlanName>
                    <pricingTier>${functionPricingTier}</pricingTier>

                    <hostJson>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/host.json</hostJson>
                <!--    <localSettingsJson>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/local.settings.json</localSettingsJson> -->

                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>17</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>

                    <funcPort>7072</funcPort>

                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    <!--    <property>
                            <name>MAIN_CLASS</name>
                            <value>com.azlearning.functionapp.AzEmailSenderFunctionApplication</value>
                        </property> -->
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!--        <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.azlearning.functionapp.AzEmailSenderFunctionApplication</mainClass>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>
                                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                </exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.31.RELEASE</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


//@SpringBootApplication(exclude = //{org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class AzEmailSenderFunctionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AzEmailSenderFunctionApplication.class, args);
    }

}


@Component
public class EmailSenderFunctionHandler {

    private final EmailSender emailSender;

    public EmailSenderFunctionHandler(EmailSender emailSender) {
        this.emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    @FunctionName("emailSender")
    public String execute(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {
                    HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<EmailDTO>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        context.getLogger().info("Get Body value : " + request.getHeaders());
        context.getLogger().info("Get Body value : " + request.getUri());

        context.getLogger().info("Get Body value : " + request.getBody());

        if(!request.getBody().isPresent()) {
            return "Please pass a emailDTO in the request body";
        }

        EmailDTO emailDTO = request.getBody().get();

        context.getLogger().info("From : " + emailDTO.getFrom());
        context.getLogger().info("To : " + emailDTO.getTo());
        context.getLogger().info("Subject : " + emailDTO.getSubject());
        context.getLogger().info("Body : " + emailDTO.getBody());
        return emailSender.apply(emailDTO);

    }
}


Provide your GsonAutoconfiguration class.

Its from Spring Framework class path. I didn't created any GsonAutoConfiguration class

Did you create a spring boot application and add the azure-functions dependency?

Provide your EmailDTO class

Check below answer @springbootlearner.

To resolve gson error locally, you have to add gson dependency in pom.xml explicitly.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>

Create a Spring Boot Azure function with below project structure, refer GitHub repository for the sample project.
Project Structure:
C:.
|   .classpath
|   .gitignore
|   .project
|   mvnw
|   mvnw.cmd
|   pom.xml
|
+---.github
|
+---.mvn
|   \---wrapper
|           maven-wrapper.properties
|
+---.settings
|
+---src
|   +---main
|   |   +---azure
|   |   |       host.json
|   |   |       local.settings.json
|   |   |
|   |   \---java
|   |       \---com
|   |           \---example
|   |               |   DemoApplication.java
|   |               |   Hello.java
|   |               |   HelloHandler.java
|   |               |
|   |               \---model
|   |                       Greeting.java
|   |                       User.java
|   |
|   \---test
|       +---java
|       |   \---com
|       |       \---example
|       |           |   HelloTest.java
|       |           |
|       |           \---loadtest
|       |                   LoadTest.java
|       |
|       \---resources
|               gatling.conf
|
\---target
    |   hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    |   hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original

Update the dependencies versions in pom.xml as below:
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Hello Spring Function on Azure</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.22.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>3.0.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <spring.cloud.function.dependencies>4.0.0</spring.cloud.function.dependencies>
        <functionResourceGroup>resource_group_name</functionResourceGroup>
        <functionAppServicePlanName>AppService_Plan</functionAppServicePlanName>
        <functionAppName>Function_App_Name</functionAppName>
        <functionAppRegion>Region</functionAppRegion>
        <functionPricingTier>Pricing Tier</functionPricingTier>

        <start-class>com.example.DemoApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.function.dependencies}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com.example.loadtest.*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceGroup>${functionResourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
                    <appServicePlanName>${functionAppServicePlanName}</appServicePlanName>
                    <pricingTier>${functionPricingTier}</pricingTier>

                    <hostJson>${project.basedir}/src/main/azure/host.json</hostJson>
                    <localSettingsJson>${project.basedir}/src/main/azure/local.settings.json</localSettingsJson>

                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>17</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

DemoApplication.java:
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

HelloHandler.java:
package com.example;

import com.example.model.Greeting;
import com.example.model.User;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;
import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker;

import java.util.Optional;

public class HelloHandler extends FunctionInvoker<User, Greeting> {

    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage execute(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        User user = request.getBody()
                .filter((u -> u.getName() != null))
                .orElseGet(() -> new User(
                        request.getQueryParameters()
                                .getOrDefault("name", "world")));
        context.getLogger().info("Greeting user name: " + user.getName());
        return request
                .createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(handleRequest(user, context))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
    }
}


Able to run the application as expected:
Console Output:
C:\Users\uname\hello-spring-function-azure>mvn azure-functions:run                                         
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.example:hello >--------------------------
[INFO] Building Hello Spring Function on Azure 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-functions:1.22.0:run (default-cli) @ hello ---
[INFO] Function App's staging directory found at: C:\Users\uname\hello-spring-function-azure\target\azure-functions\my-spring-function
4.0.6280
[INFO] Azure Functions Core Tools found.

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-12-19T10:44:51.454Z] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

Functions:

        hello: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/hello

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-12-19T10:44:52.764Z] Worker process started and initialized.
//Removed few logs
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.372Z] INFO: Searching for start class in manifest: jar:file:/C:/Users/uname/hello-spring-function-azure/target/azure-functions/my-spring-function/lib/spring-cloud-function-core-4.0.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.376Z] Dec 19, 2024 4:14:55 PM org.springframework.cloud.function.utils.FunctionClassUtils getStartClass    
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.379Z] INFO: Searching for start class in manifest: jar:file:/C:/Users/uname/hello-spring-function-azure/target/azure-functions/my-spring-function/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
//Removed few logs
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.740Z]  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.1)
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.754Z] ======> SOURCE: class com.example.DemoApplication
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.815Z] Dec 19, 2024 4:14:55 PM org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger logStarting
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.818Z] INFO: Starting application using Java 21.0.4 with PID 24984 (started by user in C:\Users\uname \hello-spring-function-azure\target\azure-functions\my-spring-function)
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.820Z] Dec 19, 2024 4:14:55 PM org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication logStartupProfileInfo
[2024-12-19T10:44:55.822Z] INFO: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2024-12-19T10:44:56.247Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-12-19T10:44:56.658Z] Dec 19, 2024 4:14:56 PM org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger logStarted
[2024-12-19T10:44:56.660Z] INFO: Started application in 1.196 seconds (process running for 5.222)
[2024-12-19T10:44:56.672Z] Greeting user name: world
[2024-12-19T10:44:56.708Z] Function "hello" (Id: 2e6835ba-c342-4365-8a10-282e87022597) invoked by Java Worker
[2024-12-19T10:44:56.817Z] Executed 'Functions.hello' (Succeeded, Id=2e6835ba-c342-4365-8a10-282e87022597, Duration=2270ms)



Not sure this answer is intended for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79286402/spring-cloud-function-for-azure-is-throwing-error-with-main-class-is-not-getting question. Still in the provided answer your using Azure function with just core Java. In your code its not using spring framework that's why its working. My actual intention was to use spring cloud function with Azure function so I get the benefit of Spring features.

I will update the answer.

Check the updated answer @springbootlearner.

Here the issue is with latest Spring Boot version with latest Spring Cloud Function. Could you try to upgrade your spring boot version to 3.4.x

Sure, I will check and update.
